# How to detect a UIViewController finish loading?

Tags: ios, viewdidload

I am doing an application that every time an UIViewController finishes loading, there is a thread take an screen shot of the current visible ViewController.
I have more than 40 ViewControllers.
How can I detect a ViewContrller finished loading.
I do not want to add that function for each "ViewDidLoad".
Thank you.

Comment: why would you need to add it to each individual `–viewDidLoad` method? have you not heard about _inheritance_?

Comment: If I use inheritance, the superclass finished loading does not mean that subclass finished loading.That function takes screen shot once the father finished loading, it does not wait the child finishes loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious and maintainable way to do this would be to create your own subclass of UIViewController that does this in ViewDidLoad, and then change all your view controllers to be instances of this new subclass.

Comment: But the superclass finished loading does not mean that subclass finished loading.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstand how subclasses work. The viewDidLoad event happens only once, at one time. If one of your view controllers does not override viewDidLoad, the superclass implementation runs. If it does override viewDidLoad, the first line should (pretty much always) say `[super viewDidLoad];` to run the superclass implementation before doing any subclass-specific behavior. Recent XCode analyzers even warn you if you leave out this call to the superclass.